# How to get prices from tradegg.it and the Steam APIs?

Tags: javascript, api, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, browser

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that gets the item's prices from tradegg.it and Steam market, and compare the prices.

I got stuck on how to get the prices. Do I need the auth info from the browser? Or will it be sent automatically by the browser because it's stored in cookies?

This is my first big project any suggestion or keywords will be much appreciated.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question I have to guess you're using `fetch` which omits cookies by default so you need to add credentials: 'same-origin' or  credentials: 'include', look for examples, see also https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS localStorage/cookies to get the current logged in user, but I would suggest to use oauth if the website supports it